# Jquery\ASP.NET draggable and resizable list of items

Tags: asp.net, jquery, draggable, resizable

Need to implement draggable and resizable list of items using Jquery or ASP.NET controls. Any code snippets or links?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't already tried it (you're question seems rather elementary), [jQuery UI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) should be all you need, or perhaps some combination of [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable) and [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable).